# css - get rid of redundant margins in grid layout

Tags: css

I am trying to get a grid display.

I created divs with inline-block display and margin-right.

My problem is that the last item on each row also has a margin-right which is redundant.

This is my CSS

```
.item{
    height:20px; 
    width:50px; 
    background:red;
    margin-right:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:2px solid black;
}

.container{
    background-color:green;
    width:270px;
}
```

this is an example HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

This is a fiddle to demonstrate what I have
http://jsfiddle.net/8HPWn/

in the project, each item's width can vary, so I cannot assume it is every Nth child or something like that.

How can I get rid of redundant margin-rights?

Comment: How do you want the outcome to be? Like this? http://pasteboard.co/2GBHw8nw.png

Comment: @Colandus - yes. that's exactly that. I don't mind if there is blank space on the right if the container is wider, but currently I have to have space on the right..

Comment: Work with media queries in combination with pseudo selectors

Comment: so you have variable width items (I take it the width above is just for demonstration then) that you want align to the right edge?

Comment: I can't think of any way to do it with pure css. There may be one, but I'd resort to JavaScript in this case, or reconsider my layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way I can think of doing this in pure CSS but it requires some additional markup:

Add an inner container:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add `overflow: hidden` to `.container`

```
.container{
    background-color:green;
    width:270px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Use `calc` to adjust the width of `.inner` to accommodate your margin nad use a negative margin to compensate:

```
.inner {
    width: calc(100%+50px);
    margin-right: -50px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

[- Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8HPWn/2/)

[- Browser support for calc](http://caniuse.com/calc)